# How to get web role input endpoint in worker role?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

We have an Azure application, which has a worker role and a web role, and the worker role has to know the web role address exposed to outside. That's because, web role include some Web API that worker role can use, so we need to know the exactly url address of web role.

Any way to get that?

Comment: If I understand correctly, if your web and worker role are deployed in a cloud service named `abc` you would want to find out the URL `abc.cloudapp.net` programmatically. Is my understanding correct? or if `abc.cloudapp.net` is mapped to a custom domain name (say `mywebsite.com`) you would want to find `mywebsite.com` programmatically?

Comment: @GauravMantri actually, we don't need to know the exactly domain name which can be seen by user, we just want to use it internally, which might be the IP address (including port) of running web role instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into [`Role`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.role.aspx), [`RoleInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleinstance.aspx), [`RoleInstanceEndpoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleinstanceendpoint.aspx) classes in [`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.aspx) Namespace. Using these you should be able to find the IP address and Port of all the role instances.

Comment: For web role, if I have multiple instances, does it matter? Do I need to get the current instance for web role?

Comment: Since `RoleInstanceEndpoint` will give you the IP address of individual instance, I don't think it would matter as your worker role will communicate with webrole on this IP address.

Comment: Yes, I use the first instance to get IP address: `var webRoleEndPoint = RoleEnvironment.Roles["CloudWebPortal"].Instances[0].InstanceEndpoints["WebPortalEndPointHttps"];`